# neural network training using back propagation issue

Tags: c++, neural-network, backpropagation, mnist

This is the code I used to classify the handwritten digits of MNist database using back-propagation algorithm on an one-layered perceptron with 10 neurons. The digits are saved in an expanded (`1`'s in last column) integer 2d matrix `images[60000][785]` and the labels in `int tlabels[60000][10]`. Every label contains a `1` in the position corresponding to the digits value and `0`'s in the rest (digits are `0`–`9`).

```
// weights1[785][10] has been initialized to random values on [-0.5,0.5] in the constructor. 
// bias of neurons have been taken into account as the last row of the matrix.
// b is the learning rate , equal to 0.5.

const int Ninput=784;
const int Noutput=10;
float result[Noutput];
for (int epoch =0 ; epoch < 30 ; epoch ++) { 
    float error =0;
    for (int sample=0 ; sample < 1000 ; sample++) {

        for (int output= 0 ; output< Noutput; output++) {
            float sum = 0;
            for (int input = 0 ; input < Ninput+1; input++)
                sum += weights1[input][output]*images[sample][input];
            result[output] = sum;
        }
        float delta[Noutput];
        for (int output= 0 ; output< Noutput;  output++) {
            delta[output]=(tlabels[sample][output]-sigmoid(result[output]))*sigmoidDerivative(result[output]);
            error+= pow((tlabels[sample][output]-sigmoid(result[output])),2.0);    
        }
        for (int output= 0 ; output< Noutput; output++)
            for (int input=0 ; input < Ninput+1 ; input++)
                weights1[input][output] = weights1[input][output] +b*delta[output]*images[sample][input];
    }
    cout << error / 1000.0;
}
```

The `error` variable converges to 0.9 , meaning this code classifies all the digits into one of the classes, even though the samples are equally distributed among the classes. Is there a logical error in the code, or should I try different sets of parameters until the results become acceptable?

Comment: You need to train it several times get good weighs values.

Comment: no matter how many epochs I use the samples are always classified in one -seemingly random- class. The mean square error converges , it doesnt improve.

Comment: Your code is a bit messy and I cant really see if.you are backpropagating the error properly

Comment: One-layer network is a linear system. In your case it has 10 rows and 735 columns. It's not possible to solve it. You can use non linear approximation of your problem. Use more layers.

Comment: It is common practice for "sigmoid derivative" functions to expect the sigmoid-squashed output, rather than the sum before the transfer function.  This kind of function evaluates `x * (1.0 - x)`.  This saves computation time when `sigmoid(x)` is already available.  So, because your `result[]` values have not been passed through the sigmoid transfer function yet, make sure your `sigmoidDerivative` function was not made for this shortcut, and effectively evaluates `sigmoid(x) * (1.0 - sigmoid(x))`.

Comment: Indeed , the input sigmoid derivative function uses is sigmoid's function output. I added a hidden layer today with 40 neurons and the error seems to go down to almost 0 after >50 epochs so the problem is solved. Thank you for your help.